# Mathematical Algorithm to test if 2 input list of n size have at least one element in common

Tags: algorithm, list

I am kinda new to the whole "algorithm" thing and I am currently working on a problem to figure out an algorithm (not coding in any specific language) to check whether or not 2 input lists of size *n* have at least one element in common.

I have an idea how to actually program it, but I can't figure out how to put this into an algorithm.

```
function checkCommon(arr1, arr2)
{
    foreach(arr1 as val1)
    {
        foreach(arr2 as val2)
        {
            if(val1 == val2)
            { 
               return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Again, I am not trying to code this, I am simply trying to create an "Algorithm" for this.

Comment: Seems like you algo is correct. Its complexity is O(size1 * size2) but it works. You may improve complexity to O(size1 * log(size2)) if elements of arr2 can be sorted.

Comment: @TheGuyzer: What do you think is wrong with this particular algorithm then?

Comment: @claris Perhaps I am not understanding the task at hand... Is what I wrote considered an Algorithm?  From what I have been reading in my book i assumed algorithms looked something like L[0:n-1] = x+y (obviously that is not a real algorithm for this issue).

Comment: That is just a notation for writing pseudocode when devising algorithms. The code piece you provided is another pseudocode. The book notation might be commonplace. An algorithm and its notation are two separate things. You can describe the same algorithm in many different notations.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko: Not quite. It's O(size2 * log(size2)) to sort arr2, and then O(size1 * log(size2)) to determine if any of the elements in arr1 exist in arr2. Now, if you could load arr2 into a hash set, it'd be O(size1 + size2), with O(size2) additional memory.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, you are right. What is more with reference to OP's question we can assume *size1 = size2 = n*.

Comment: @Ivan: So then the complexity of your suggestion becomes O(n log n) + O(n log n)? So you were right, it's O(n log n). Whereas the OP's solution is O(n^2).